# How would corporations look like if the conglomerates are banned?

Tags: economy, law

I want to have a setting where legal system allows stocks to be owned only by the individuals. Meaning Joe could own stocks at Acme corporation, but LexCorp can't own stocks in Acme corporation. If LexCorp acquires Acme, either:

1. Acme ceases to exist and all of it's assets and obligations belong to LexCorp
2. Acme & LexCorp consolidate and become a single new company that owns all assets and obligations from both of them.

How would corporations look like in my economy?

Comment: If a company cannot own stocks from another one, how can a company buy another one in your setting ? (It might be impossible, just asking if this is planned already)

Comment: @Thalantas The acquired company will cease to exist and all of it's assets will become part of the buyer. Or they could merge and consolidate into new company.

Comment: What you are calling individuals are known in law as natural persons. There is a tendency in some jurisdictions to grant corporate persons (businesses, companies, institutions) the same rights and protections as natural persons.

Comment: It all depends on the way you introduce it. If it'll be in one country, every "owner" corporations will just move somewhere else and nothing changes, for example.

Comment: This is a very open ended question. I am voting to close as too broad. If you can think of a more specific question, please edit and we can re-open this post.

Comment: @Mołot - no, it's not that simple. A country can prohibit a foreign legal entity to own stock in domestic companies (real life example: restrictions on buying Chinese stocks)

Comment: These companies would lose value or, well, stop being domestic. There is always a grace period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The corporations would be far smaller, since most of the financing comes from institutional investors: pension funds, hedge funds, insurance companies, mutual funds etc.

The bonds market would be far larger because all that money from institutional investors must go somewhere.

You eliminate Japanese keiretsu and Korean chaebol.

You also eliminate German type of long term relationship between banks and companies where bank holds shares in friendly corporations and loans them money on lower rates since it has directors on the boards who share information with it.

Transparency would be far larger, since you can't hold share in a company that holds shares in a company that owns the yacht that you are using. Tax man would find you in a blink of an eye.

Management would have far more power since it's much harder for small investors to organize themselves to protect their interests. Few institutional investors could get much easily enough votes to oust the CEO.

Answer (score 6):

The original purpose of the corporation was risk management. The original corporation allowed individuals to participate in a risky venture without being personally ruined if the venture went bad. Their liability was limited to however much they put in when they bought their shares (hence "limited liability corporation")

Corporations today manage risk by separating different operating divisions into separate companies so that if something goes wrong in one branch, that branch can be liquidated without destroying all the other, perfectly profitable branches.

Without the ability to manage risk within a conglomerate, corporations would be a lot more risk-averse. (Of course, this might be a good thing, maybe ...)

If you are going to mess with corporations, I suggest you read the following:

1. The Corporation that Changed the World by Nick Robins, a history of the East India Company, a rather unique original prototype of the idea
2. Monsoon by Robert Kaplan, an examination of the re-emergence of the Indian Ocean as the primary theater of global geopolitics in the 21st century
3. The Influence of Sea Power Upon History: 1660-1783 by Alfred Thayer Mahan, a classic examination of how naval power is the most critical link between political, cultural, military and business forces.
4. The Post-American World by Fareed Zakaria, an examination of the structure of the world being created, not by the decline of America, but by the “rise of the rest.”
5. The Lever of Riches by Joel Mokyr, probably the most compelling model and account of how technological change drives the evolution of civilizations, through monotonic, path-dependent accumulation of changes.

If this question is not central enough to your project to warrant that much research, you can read a [good overview by Rao at Ribbonfarm](http://www.ribbonfarm.com/2011/06/08/a-brief-history-of-the-corporation-1600-to-2100/).

Answer (score 4):

By allowing only individuals, not any other entity, to own stock, there are a few obvious implications:

- Mutual funds that invest wholly or partially in the stock market become illegal, because those are operated by corporate entities (while managed by individuals, just like an individual would be make a buy or sell order for stock or signing a contract to that effect while representing a company).
- Assuming that legislation is not watertight (except for the most trivial of cases it never is, and for those cases, there are always unintended side effects), and assuming that this change is made in an existing economy where such legislation is not enacted, companies would be looking for ways to evade it, for example by paying individuals to hold stock for them and represent the company at stockholder events.

It also creates all sorts of hassles when one company buys another. Even taking at face value your comment

> The acquired company will cease to exist and all of it's assets will become part of the buyer. Or they could merge and consolidate into new company.

there's still the issue of contracts of all kinds that were entered for the bought company. Even something as simple as building ownership or leases, let alone employment contracts, would need to be managed in light of this. That's hardly impossible, but it does bring with it several truckloads (not just cans) of worms that need to be handled within the legal framework thus established.

Generally speaking, you can't change just one small detail and expect other things to remain the same, as everything is interconnected to a lesser or greater degree.

Take your example

> Joe could own stocks at Acme corporation, but LexCorp can't own stocks in Acme corporation.

Now, Alice works for Acme Corp, and LexCorp seems that Acme Corp is selling really high quality thromblemeisters, and have a great reputation in the market. LexCorp wants to get into the thromblemeisters market but have been unable to make their own at a sufficiently high quality, so they want to buy Acme Corp and simply keep manufacturing thromblemeisters in the same way. Alice has an employment agreement with Acme Corp. When LexCorp buys Acme Corp, if Acme Corp ceases to exist, that employment agreement is suddenly no longer valid, and a new one needs to be entered between Alice and LexCorp. Acme Corp were leasing manufacturing tools, and those agreements are between Acme Corp and some other company; the leases need to somehow be transferred to LexCorp instead. And so on.

None of that is impossible, and you could even design laws and legal practices to allow for it to happen "automatically", but at that point, **one has to wonder what the point is of not simply allowing LexCorp to own all of the stock in Acme Corp** and keep all the other legal paperwork untouched because Acme Corp is still Acme Corp, just the ownership has changed.

After all, companies can still have multiple divisions that do disparate things which are sold under different brand names, and the profits (and losses) end up in roughly the same place.

Comment: Corporations have legal heir, all their contractual agreements go to the new buyer or the consolidated company, that includes employee contracts, lease contracts, etc. That's the way it works now and in my world.

Comment: Your point about mutual funds is a good one. Still, it seems likely that people could come up with something else that effectively serves more or less the same purpose. For example, instead of investing in a fund, you might contract the services of an investment consultancy firm, authorizing them to buy, sell and possibly vote stocks on your behalf, subject to some agreed-upon constraints. In *theory*, you'd still personally own the stocks the consultancy firm buys for you, but in practice the firm would handle everything.

Comment: ... Or, alternatively, I see no reason why mutual funds might not simply exist as a separate type of legal entity, distinct from corporations, perhaps something more like a cooperative. You could still require that only natural persons are allowed to be members of such an "investment cooperative", to avoid creating an obvious loophole. Of course, both possibilities would involve a lot of complex details that I'm simply handwaving away, but still, I don't see any *obvious* reason why one could not have *something like* mutual funds under a system like what the OP is envisioning.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen What you describe could work, but presents obvious problems from a diversification perspective. Part of the reason why mutual funds work well for individual investors is because reasonable sums of money give you the diversification of investing in tens, hundreds or even thousands of different companies' stock. For example, the US S&P 500 index covers 500 publicly traded companies. If I wanted to invest \$100, I'd be investing on average \$0.20 in each stock in the S&P 500. Because few companies trade at those levels, diversification would be difficult without lots of money.

Answer (score 4):

Dividends would be higher, for one thing. Since the corporation has no way of storing wealth, other than putting it in the bank, it presents an unnecessarily high risk, since the bank CAN go under. Far better to give it to the shareholders, who can invest in other ventures on their own.

Corporations would thus be much smaller, and less able to manage major changes in their environment, and would fail more often, which in turn would increase the risk of investment, thus leading to increase in interest rates. There would also be a lot more of them, leading to the same effect.

Banks would be delighted of course, since they tend to own debt, not equity, so the rules wouldn't bother them.

Basically, you'd have an early to mid-19th century economy, lots of risks, many bubbles, fly-by-night operations and banks calling the shots.